# Issue with Math rounding in JS failing to actually provide a whole number in favor of a decimal answer

Tags: javascript, math-functions

So I set this up for a bit of simple math to add a little flair to a madlibs game. Yet everytime I run this I get a decimal answer rather than a whole number, Math.round(x, n) doesn't work either. Is there some improper syntax or something I'm missing?

```
let height = prompt("About how tall are you like inch-wise? 48 = 4 feet, 60 = 5 feet , 72 = 6 feet."); //for height multiple in story

if (isNaN(height)) {
    height = 66;
}
else {
    height = height;
};

height = height / 12;
console.log(height);
Math.round(height);
console.log(height);
```

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript doesn't pass variables by reference and `Math.round` returns the rounded value. So you have to assign the resulting value.

```
height = Math.round(height);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been trying to wrap my head around this for like 3 hours and feel a bit dumb... appreciate ya nonetheless!